# STL Object size() error in FOR routine

Tags: stl, visual-studio-2005, size

I found a strange phenomenon when using the STL functions.
I wrote a test() function.

```
bool test()
{
    list<int> t;

    for( int i = 0; i < t.size()-1; i ++ )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

when I run the test() function, return false; why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

size() return a size_t value, i.e. unsigned int, therefore  size()-1 is positive.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forget to build your program, after updating it.